# Swift - Methods is executing out of order

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am using completion on all my methods to ensure that execution flow is controlled. Yet in a very weird instance, this doesn't seem to apply. In a TableViewController (TVC), upon the user click on a row, in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, I am retrieving user info and then checking through another method for a condition. Except the retrieving starts but before it completes, the checking method occurs. How can this be happening? and how can I fix it?

Here is the code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
self.getFriendObjectDataFromBackend(self.notificationObject.from!, completion: { (result)->Void in
                if(result.domain == "")
                {
                    print(self.friendObject.name)
                    self.checkIfRequestAlreadyAccepted({ (result)->Void in
                        if(result == true)
                        {
                         ...
                        }
                    })
               }
})
```

for getFriendObjectDataFromBackend(..):

```
func getFriendObjectDataFromBackend(toUser:String, completion:(result:NSError) -> Void)
{
  .....
}
```

and for checkIfRequestAlreadyAccepted(..):

```
func checkIfRequestAlreadyAccepted(completion: (result:Bool) -> Void)
{
  .....
}
```

Error is being triggered in checkIfRequestAlreadyAccepted where I am relying to use value of global variable set by getFriendObjectDataFromBackend.

Thanks in advance for helping.

Update: Added code for getFriendObjectDataFromBackend:

```
func getFriendObjectDataFromBackend(toUser:String, completion:(result:NSError) -> Void)
    {
        var errorFound:NSError = NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
        let query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "_User")
        query.whereKey("appUsername", equalTo: toUser)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
             if(error == nil)
             {
                completion(result: errorFound)
                self.friendObject.username = objects![0]["appUsername"] as? String
                self.friendObject.name = objects![0]["appUsername"] as? String
             }else{
                errorFound = error!
                completion(result: errorFound)
             }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `getFriendObjectDataFromBackend`?  The code inside that will determine when your completion function gets called and what could be happening in the meantime.

Comment: @Putz1103 updated the post :)

Comment: You are calling the `completion(result:errorFound)` *before* you set the global values on `self.friendObject`

Comment: @Paulw11 spot on! Post as answer so that I can select it. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the completion(result:errorFound) before you set the global values on self.friendObject.  You should make sure everything is set and then call the completion handler.

```
if (error == nil)
{    
    self.friendObject.username = objects![0]["appUsername"] as? String
    self.friendObject.name = objects![0]["appUsername"] as? String
    completion(result: errorFound)
} else {
    errorFound = error!
    completion(result: errorFound)
}
```